# OSX 11.6 cut off ability to teleconference

Tags: network, big-sur, microphone

I upgraded to 11.6 last night and now I can't teleconference using BigBlueButton. It's not the tool I would choose, but I had no say. I literally have no say now; my microphone can't be accessed.

The problem is that I'm getting an Interactive Connectivity Establishment (ICE) error. The error message documentation on the error, from the provider:

> ICE negotiation failed - The browser and FreeSWITCH try to negotiate ports to use to stream the media and that negotiation failed. Possible Causes:
>
> - NAT is blocking the connection
> - Firewall is blocking the UDP connection/ports

I haven't directly changed any settings, but I have upgraded my OS. Suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS did you run before the update? Have you checked if all permissions are checked that are required in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy?

Comment: @KevinGrabher  I used 11.5 prior to the update. I try to keep my OS up to date as a defense against security risks. There aren't that many features in System Preferences that appear to be applicable. I'm going to try Apple Support.

Comment: This feature appears to be specific to Safari, version 15.0. I can use Firefox for telecommuting with Mattermost and its BigBlueButton plug-in. My employer chose that part of our toolchain because those tools can be made local as opposed to cloud-based.